How do I get parallel access to retry on "database table is locked" error?
My Django unit tests to validate the behavior of my application when multiple clients access it at the same time:
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db import connection
from django.db import transaction

class ApplicationTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_parallel(self):

        @transaction.atomic
        def local_provision(i):
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
              # Some SQL commands that read and write the person table.
              # These commands take less than one second.
              
              return f"done with {i}"
            
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(local_provision, i) for i in range(5)]
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                print(future.result())

I get:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: database table is locked: person

Changing the timeout in settings.py did not make any difference. Why isn't SQLite waiting until the file is unlocked and then retrying? How can I get SQLite to retry?
